# Child widget of CupertinoPageScaffold is behind CupertinoNavigationBar

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to put contents below a CupertinoNavigationBar.

But the content Widgets are partially covered by the CupertinoNavigationBar.

I don't understand why the child Column is not vertically offset so that the top isn't covered by the CupertinoNavigationBar.

Below is a screenshot, and my code

[image: iOS simulator screenshot]

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PersonalInfoEditor extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: buildNavigationBar(context),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Personal Info'),
          Text('t1'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  CupertinoNavigationBar buildNavigationBar(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoNavigationBar(        
        trailing: CupertinoButton(
          child: Text('Save', style: TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.activeBlue)),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Wrap your child inside `SafeArea` :

```
        return CupertinoPageScaffold(
              navigationBar: buildNavigationBar(context),
              child: SafeArea(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Personal Info'),
                    Text('t1'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
```

And don't forget to use `CupertinoApp` instead of `MaterialApp`

More info: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPageScaffold-class.html

Comment: could you provide related document in flutter docs?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPageScaffold-class.html